# Keep checked checkboxes after refresh

Tags: angular, events, checkbox

I have an array of users and one checkbox per user, if I check it, the user gets a new status. I can't keep them checked if I refresh the browser tab. I can't use radio button in this case. If I add a foreach it works but all the checkboxes are checked

**HTML**

```
       <tr scope="row" *ngFor="let user of users">
        <td class="w-25">
          <input
            class="check-btn"
            type="checkbox"
            name="premium"
            [checked]="checked"
            [ngModel]="checked"
            (click)="
              eventChecked($event.target.checked ? '1' : '0', user.id)
            "
          />
        </td>
        <td class="w-50">{{ user.name }}</td>
      </tr>
```

**TS**

```
  users: IUser[];
  checked: any;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,

  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.users = data;
        console.log(data);
        this.users.forEach(e => {
        if(e.premium == 1){
          this.checked = true;
          console.log(this.checked);          
         }
       });         
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  
  eventChecked(event: any, id: number) {
    console.log(id, event);
    this.checked = true;
    this.userService.editUser(event, id).subscribe();
  }
```

**EDIT**

One of them isn't premium but both are checked.

[image]

I want only to have checked the premium user.

Comment: You could write and read to localStorage maybe? I don't know if the users are fetched from a database somewhere, but in order to save data after a refresh, you need to save the state somewhere

Comment: No I have to keep checked them until I uncheck

Comment: Do you mean that you need to reset the state after you refresh the browser? So, if it was checked, you need to uncheck it if the browser was refreshed?

Comment: They must stay always checked until I uncheck them even if I refresh the browser or close it because it is bound to the "event" and I need it to update the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you see that all are checked if one of them are checked because the model does not account for different users.

Try changing the `checked` variable to take the user's id as a key

`checked: {[userId:string]: boolean} = {};`

The key (userId) is of type string, and the value is boolean. e.g. checked can be: `{someUserId1: false, someUserId2: false, someUserId3: true}`;

Meaning something like this:
HTML

```
    <tr scope="row" *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td class="w-25">
              <input
                class="check-btn"
                type="checkbox"
                name="premium"
                [checked]="checked[user.id]"
                [ngModel]="checked[user.id]"
                (click)="
                  eventChecked($event.target.checked ? '1' : '0', user.id)
                "
              />
            </td>
            <td class="w-50">{{ user.name }}</td>
          </tr>
```

TS

```
users: IUser[];
  checked: {[userId:string]: boolean} = {}; // the key is of type string, and the value is boolean. e.g. checked can be: {someUserId1: false, someUserId2: false};

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,

  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.users = data;
        console.log(data);
        this.users.forEach(e => {
        if(e.premium == 1){
          this.checked[e.id] = true;
          console.log(this.checked);          
         }
       });         
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  
  eventChecked(event: any, id: number) {
    console.log(id, event);
    this.checked[id] = true;
    this.userService.editUser(event, id).subscribe();
  }
```

I have not tested the code as it is, and you may have to modify it.